# How can I get the Kinect serial number with OpenNI?

Tags: c++, kinect, openni

How can I get the serial numbers of my kinect devices in OpenNI? I'm using
avin2's SensorKinect driver.

I'm trying the following, but I only get "0" in my variable `serial`:

```
xn::NodeInfoList possibleChains;
context.EnumerateProductionTrees(XN_NODE_TYPE_DEVICE,NULL,possibleChains,NULL);
for(xn::NodeInfoList::Iterator i = possibleChains.Begin(); i !=
possibleChains.End(); ++i)
    {
        xn::NodeInfo node = *i;
        nRetVal = context.CreateProductionTree(node);
        xn::Device device;
        nRetVal = node.GetInstance(device);
        XnChar serial[1024];
        device.GetIdentificationCap().GetSerialNumber(serial, 1024);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that's not possible with OpenNI yet (at least for the Kinect - maybe the avin2 driver is to blame).

However, you can get information about into which USB bus/port is the Kinect connected using `xn::NodeInfo::GetCreationInfo` ([link](http://openni.org/Documentation/Reference/classxn_1_1_node_info_aa516a6232e63d1d5080e677d7fee8b7a.html#aa516a6232e63d1d5080e677d7fee8b7a))

On linux it contains the following (for a Device NodeType):

```
045e/02ae@5/13 (idVendor/idProduct@BusID/DeviceId)
```

I cannot show you exact code, as I use OpenNI java wrapper instead of C++, but this method works for me on Mac/Linux/Win to differentiate Kinects in my applications.

The problem is, that the bus/port information will change when you connect kinect to another usb (and on linux it changes sometimes even between restarts).

But if you're on linux, you can use (as root):

```
# lsusb -v -d 045e:02ae | grep -e "Bus\|iSerial"
# Bus 005 Device 008: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
#   iSerial                 3 A00365A00972107A
# Bus 005 Device 013: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
#   iSerial                 3 A00365A00955107A
```

to get the actual serial number of the kinect.

Therefore you can come up with a bash script, that will be run before your OpenNI application starts, that will find the bus/port and pass it to your application (which can then use this information to communicate with the correct Kinect).

Answer (score 1):

With **OpenNI2**, giving wanted serial number as `wantedSerialNumber` string

```
openni::Device device = new openni::Device();
openni::Array<openni::DeviceInfo> deviceList;
openni::OpenNI::enumerateDevices(&deviceList);
for (int i = 0; i != deviceList.getSize(); ++i) {
    const openni::DeviceInfo& info = deviceList[i];
    string uri = info.getUri();
    device->open(uri.c_str());
    char serialNumber[1024];
    device->getProperty(ONI_DEVICE_PROPERTY_SERIAL_NUMBER, &serialNumber);
    if (string(serialNumber) != wantedSerialNumber) {
        device->close();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```